# RallyRestApi.dll not recognizing RallyRestApi object

Tags: c#, rally

I am following the directions here https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET to allow my C# program to go out to Rally and obtain Sprint information.  After I create the referenced .dll, changed my Framework to 4.0, and rebuild, C# does not recognize the object referenced in the next step:

"RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi("myuser@company.com", "password", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "1.40")

C# does recognize the namespace "Rally" and I did bring it in with "using Rally;"

Any tips ?  Also is there a way to find a list of all items(ex, iteration/sprint) Rally.RestApi.dll can query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Solution Explorer, under References, find Rally.RestApi. Check its version in the Properties. Is it 2.0.2, which is the latest?
Change your version of WS API in the code to v2.0. 1.40 is unsupported.

```
restApi = new RallyRestApi("myuser@company.com", "password", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "v2.0");
```

Do you have `Rally.RestApi` and `Rally.RestApi.Response` in `using`?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Rally.RestApi;
using Rally.RestApi.Response;
```

you may see some full code examples [here](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/rally-dot-net-rest-apps).